# Django select_related does not work properly

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a JOIN request from my database via Django ORM. But select_related does not work properly.
SQL request I'm trying to get:

```
SELECT * FROM rel_observation_table
inner join sp_fields on rel_observation_table.id_field = sp_fields.id
```

My 1st table model

```
class RelSubdivisionFields(models.Model):
    id_sp_subdivision = models.ForeignKey('SpSubdivision', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_sp_subdivision', blank=True, null=True)
    id_field = models.ForeignKey('SpFields', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_field')
    block = models.ForeignKey('SpFormBlocks', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='block')
    order_index = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    required = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'rel_subdivision_fields'
        unique_together = (('id_sp_subdivision', 'id_field', 'block'),)
```

My 2nd table model

```
class SpFields(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rel_table = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sp_fields'
```

My QuerySet

```
qs = RelObservationFields.objects.select_related('id_field')
```

Result of QS execution

```
>>> qs.values()[0]
{'id_sp_observation_id': 80101, 'id_field_id': 1, 'block_id': 'with_error', 'order_index': 0, 'required': False, 'id': 90}
```

As you can see, there are only columns from first table, I also need ones from the second.

Comment: `select_related()` should point to the related model instead of the attribute.

Comment: `values()` when given no arguments returns all fields for the model and any annotations, it does not select fields from any joins/related models